# Is there any research on where (on the physical screen) people prefer to read content

Tags: scrolling, research

For example, on a page full with content, where at the bottom near the fold there is some content. Where do users tend to scroll to to read this content?

Will they read it where it is, at the bottom of the page, or do they scroll it up to a higher area of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Andy, that would depend on the content on the screen and all other UI elements that draw attention, the lay-out of the page and the type of application that page is part of.

But in general people tend to read in the middle of their page rather than the top or the bottom and they tend to scroll in 1-7 line chunks in very text heavy pages as illustrated by the study conducted by Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/PETMEI2015scrolling_petmei_15_final.pdf

It has an admittedly small sample size, but it's hard to find trustworthy research on this topic.

---

If your question is less about the reading/scrolling behaviour and more about whether or not your users will notice/find your content. You can use tools like VisualEyes to generate a AI-driven heatmap of your design